# Don't reset page numbering when a new part starts

Tags: page-numbering, parts

I am just learning LaTeX, so this might be a very obvious question, but unfortunetely I haven't found any answer on this forum, or anywhere else.

I have a document (book) with multiple parts and chapters, but when a new part starts the page numbering goes back to 1. Is there an option to disable this automatic reset?

I am looking forward to your respons!

Kind regards

[image]

---

I think I found the problem! I created a few days ago a function to create new parts without the page numbering on the whitepage of the new part. So it turns the page numbering off creates the page and then turns it on again. But it probably turns it on back to 1.

Is there an easy way to store the page number before it is turned off? Or is there in general an easier way to do this?

```
\newcommand{\createpart}[2]
  {
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{with}}
    {\part{#1}}
    {\part*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  }
```

Comment: Which class are you using? `book` class does not reset page numbers after `part`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) this is not normal behaviour so please post a full minimal example giving this kind of out put.

Comment: `\pagenumbering` always resets the page number to 1

Answer (score 4):

Don't fiddle with page numbers, just use `\pagestyle{empty}` (or `\thispagestyle{empty}`) for the `\part` page. This has worked for me:

```
\part[Title]{Title\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

which puts `Title` in the ToC and `Title` plus `\thispagestyle{empty}` in the document body. However, if you use the `memoir` class just put:

```
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
```

in your preamble (without fiddling with each `\part{...}`)

Comment: Well, either me or you seem to have misunderstood the question -- isn't the question about preventing page number reset with every `\part`? If that is true, I don't see how the `empty` pagestyle comes in... Please correct me, if I am wrong -- I will delete this comment then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't know of any class where `\part` resets the page numbering.  The asker said that a new definition of `\part` was used to turn off page number printing on `\part` pages which resulted in page number resetting. I responded to what I thought was the underlying question of how to turn off the printing of the page number. If you think I'm right please upvote my answer.

Comment: In some sense we're both right ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The question was not the clearest that I have seen. I have expanded my answer and thanks for the vote.

Answer (score -3):

I found an answer!

With the \newcounter command you can save a variable temporarily. So the code below saves the page nubmer temporarily and than sets the pagenumber back when the arabic pagenumbering is reinstated. :)

```
\newcommand{\createpart}[2]
  {
  \newcounter{tempPageNumber}
  \setcounter{tempPageNumber}{\thepage}
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{with}}
    {\part{#1}}
    {\part*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \setcounter{page}{\value{tempPageNumber}}
  }
```

Comment: Again, this is useless to anyone else without knowing what document class you are using.

Comment: Why create a new counter each time this macro is executed? Again information about the class would help a lot. For example in the memoir class, removing the page number from all part pages is a one liner in the preamble.

Comment: Also to second @daleif's comment: You can't use your `\createpart` macro twice or even more, since `\newcounter` is a macro that defines counters globally -- it will complain about `tempPageNumber` being defined already. Also, don't rely on `\thepage` printing pure numbers only, so `\setcounter{tempPageNumber}{\thepage}` may fail miserably

Comment: Each time you are using `\pagnumbering` the page counter is reset to one. Adding an auxiliary counter to store a value and revode it later is kind of pointless since resetting the pagecounter is unwanted and unneeded in the first place.